Maximise norm over the boundary of a convex set
Let $K\subset \mathbb R^2$ be compact, convex and connected. What is the know numerical scheme to find the extremal points of $K$?
Denote by $\partial K$ the collection of all extremal points of $K$. Does there exist a "quick search" method for
$$\max_{x\in\partial K} |x|^2?$$
This question is related to An optimisation problem Similar question has been posted here Convex maximization over the boundary of a convex set
